# Popup Website in Webview apps

Tags: java, android

i build an android webview app and have some problem when the website have pop up content.

the java code is here :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cek_pesawat, container, false);
    String url = "http://klikmbc.co.id/getbook/print.php";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewPesawat);
    view.setInitialScale(400);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


    view.loadUrl(url);
    return rootView;
}
```

the view when app run that have pop up content.

[image]

when click button "Cetak tiket" it will show pop up.

example in website : http://klikmbc.co.id/getbook/print.php

Comment: so you want to a this popup ?

Comment: You cannot popup a website. Remember when you 'accidentally' clicked an ad on your browser in you mobile phone? did it show any popup? or did the browser opened and redirected you to another page?

Comment: You can create a 'popup' like fragment(Dialog in Android) and style it like a popup, and show the wanted page in this WebView Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

try this

add `view`  to `rootView`

```
rootView.addView(view);
```

then `@Override` method  `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```